# How to read huge binary file and get a certain columns array in Python3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I try to get python array from a [soapy](https://github.com/xmikos/soapy_power) binary  file.this binary file size is 6G,has 12 columns with uncertain rows, looks like below:

```
ss2017-03-17, 13:18:25, 88000000.0, 90560000.0, 426666.666667, 647168, -98.6323, -98.7576, -97.3716, -98.3133, -98.8829, -98.9333
ss2017-03-17, 13:18:25, 90560000.0, 93120000.0, 426666.666667, 647168, -95.7163, -96.2564, -97.01, -98.1281, -90.701, -88.0872
ss2017-03-17, 13:18:25, 93120000.0, 95680000.0, 426666.666667, 647168, -99.0242, -91.3061, -91.9134, -85.4561, -86.0053, -97.8411
ss2017-03-17, 13:18:26, 95680000.0, 98240000.0, 426666.666667, 647168, -94.2324, -83.7932, -78.3108, -82.033, -89.1212, -97.4499
```

After

```
f = np.fromfile(open('filename','rb'))
print(f.ndim)
```

I got a one dimension array.
How to read this binary file and get array has 12 elements per row?

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your data like this:

```
np.array(data).reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just reshape it with `-1`, this will infer the number of rows.

```py
f = np.fromfile(open('filename','rb'))
f = f.reshape(-1, 12)
print(f.ndim)
```

Note that this will fail if the size of the array is not a multiple of 12, for whatever reason. I'd suggest checking the shape first if this matters to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.When the file is more than 5G,is possiible to have only one `f` in script?

Comment: That depends on how much RAM your computer has. If you've got 10 GB free, then there's room for 2, basically. I'd recommend having a look at `numpy.memmap` since this lets you work with huge files on disk. You can slice out parts of the array and then you will simply read the necessary parts into memory at one time. Alternatively, `dask.array` lets you do this on small bits at a time (see chunksize).